# The number of roots for this equation

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

To find the number of roots of $2\cos^{2} \theta=1+3^{\sin \theta}+3^{\csc \theta}$ in the interval [0,$2\pi$]

I was only able to simplify it to

$\cos 2\theta=3^{\sin \theta}+3^{\csc \theta}$

I'm uncertain on how to proceed after this .

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: First note that your expression on the RHS is not defined on your interval $[0,2\pi]$ for $x=0,\pi,2\pi$. Further, you may rewrite the equation into one with only $s=\sin x$ and now consider the equation
$2(1-s^2)=1+3^s + 3^{\frac 1s}$ for $|s|\leq 1, s \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial:**
You have that
$$3^{\sin(\theta)}+3^{\csc(\theta)}=\cos(2\theta)\leq 1$$
So:

$$3^{\sin(\theta)}\leq 1 \Rightarrow \sin(\theta)\leq 0$$
But $\sin(\theta)\neq 0$(otherwise cosecant is not defined), so $\sin(\theta)<0$

So a first restriction is $\theta \in (\pi,2\pi)$
Notice now that the LHS function, and the RHS function are symmetrical respect to $\theta=\frac 32 \pi$. So you can restrict even more to $(\pi,\frac 32 \pi)$(I verified and $\frac 32 \pi$ is not a solution).
Moreover $cos(2\theta)$ has to be $>0$(it's sum of two exponentials in base 3). So our interval reduces even more to $(\pi,\frac 54 \pi)$.